# Need to set main.account = sub.account where main.id = sub.id

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query, I need to write an update that will set mabi accountid = mb glinventory for each of the outputs that this select statement gives. This is what my select statement pulls

| mabi.itemid | mabi.accountid | mb.glinventory | mb.itemid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 758711763075273754 | 0 | 735174926379018147 | 758711763075273754 |
| 758711763074225163 | 0 | 735174926320297568 | 758711763074225163 |
| 758711763075273753 | 0 | 735174926379018147 | 758711763075273753 |
| 758711763074225169 | 0 | 735174926320297568 | 758711763074225169 |
| 758711763075273749 | 0 | 735174926320297568 | 758711763075273749 |
| 758711763074225162 | 0 | 735174926379018147 | 758711763074225162 |

Basically, I need to set the mabi accountid = mb glinventory for the rows in my output if that makes sense

```sql
SELECT
  mabi.businessactionitemid,
  mabi.accountid,
  mb.glinventory,
  mb.businessactionitemid
FROM
  mabusinessactionitem mabi
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      mabi.accountid,
      cat.glinventory,
      mabi.businessactionitemid
    FROM
      cocategory cat
      INNER JOIN mabusinessactionitem mabi ON cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
    WHERE
      cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
      AND mabi.businessactionitemid IN (
        SELECT
          businessactionitemid
        FROM
          mabusinessactionitem mabi
          INNER JOIN mabusinessaction maba ON maba.businessactionid = mabi.businessactionid
        WHERE
          documentnumber = '32103'
          AND STATUS != 1
          AND accountid = 0
      )
  ) mb ON mb.businessactionitemid = mabi.businessactionitemid;
```

This is the select statement that pulls those outputs, I need to write an update to do what I described above. Im not sure of the best way to do it, I have tried

```sql
UPDATE mabi
SET mabi.accountid = mb.glinventory
FROM mabusinessactionitem mabi
JOIN (
    SELECT mabi.accountid,
        cat.glinventory,
        mabi.businessactionitemid
    FROM cocategory cat
    INNER JOIN mabusinessactionitem mabi ON cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
    WHERE cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
        AND mabi.businessactionitemid IN (
            SELECT businessactionitemid
            FROM mabusinessactionitem mabi
            INNER JOIN mabusinessaction maba ON maba.businessactionid = mabi.businessactionid
            WHERE documentnumber = '32103'
                AND STATUS != 1
                AND accountid = 0
            )
    ) mb ON mb.businessactionitemid = mabi.businessactionitemid;
```

I've done things similar, is this the right route, how would I complete this task. I effectively need to do

```sql
UPDATE mabi
SET mabi.accountid = mb.glinventory
WHERE mabi.itemid = mb.itemid
```

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] with emphasis on **minimal** i.e. strip the problem down to the bare minimum required to demonstrate the issue you have. No one is going to spend time trying to understand a really complex query. Especially when you haven't made any effort to format your query into something readable - which I highly recommend you do - once you have a minimal version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it looked formatted when I went to post it but there was some disparity. A minimal reproducible example should be what I put at the bottom, let me know if I need to add anymore.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: ERROR: relation "mabi" does not exist, refering to the first FROM
  mabusinessactionitem mabi, it it because the mabusinessactionitem table is referenced twice with the same alias @LordBaconPants

Comment: @LordBaconPants when trying your answer, the error in my comment above is what I get

Comment: @LordBaconPants Im gonna have someone look at it tomorrow, your comment confirms my suspicions on how it should be formatted, let me know if you would like an update if I can resolve it

Comment: @learning with the use of Join I wasnt able to get it to work either

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is actually correct. Just to combine it all together like this will do

```
UPDATE mabi
SET mabi.accountid = mb.glinventory
FROM mabi
JOIN mb
ON mabi.itemid = mb.itemid
```

If you need to check and filter by mabi.accountid, you can add a WHERE condition at the back. Like where mabi.accountid = 0

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, by the looks. You just need to join mabi and MB together:

```
UPDATE
  mabi
SET
  mabi.accountid = mb.glinventory
FROM
  mabusinessactionitem mabi 
  INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
  mabi.accountid,
  cat.glinventory,
  mabi.businessactionitemid
FROM
  cocategory cat
  INNER JOIN mabusinessactionitem mabi ON cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
WHERE
  cat.categoryid = mabi.categoryid
  AND mabi.businessactionitemid IN (
    SELECT
      businessactionitemid
    FROM
      mabusinessactionitem mabi
      INNER JOIN mabusinessaction maba ON maba.businessactionid = mabi.businessactionid
    WHERE
      documentnumber = '32103'
      AND STATUS != 1
      AND accountid = 0
      )
  ) mb ON mb.accountid = mabi.accountid;
```

Comment: wouldnt I be joining on the itemid as thats the similarity between them